# How do I create a view, select from it, and join it with an existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

So here's the code producing the data that I want for table 1.

```
with data as 
(
    select
        CP_REF,
        count(*) * 1.0 /
          nullif(count(case when QUANTITY > 0 then 1 end), 0) as ADI,
          stdevp(QUANTITY) / nullif(avg(QUANTITY), 0) as COV
    from 
        DF_ALL_DEMAND_BY_ROW_V
    where 
        parent is not null
    group by 
        CP_REF
)
select
    CP_REF, ADI, COV
    case
        when ADI <  1.32 and COV * COV <  0.49 then 'Smooth'
        when ADI >= 1.32 and COV * COV <  0.49 then 'Intermittent'
        when ADI <  1.32 and COV * COV >= 0.49 then 'Erratic'
        when ADI >= 1.32 and COV * COV <= 0.49 then 'Lumpy'
        else 'No Quantity Measured'
    end
from data;
```

This provides a very elegant solution like this...

[image]

This is what I'm looking for, however, now I need to take this data and join it with the original table `DF_ALL_DEMAND_BY_ROW_V`. I want it to have everything that exists in `DF_ALL_DEMAND_BY_ROW_V` but joining the data above on `CP_REF`, which I think is a `LEFT JOIN` but I can't figure it out.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you mean however why not create a second CTE and join to that, eg

```
with data as (
    select
    ...
), Q2 as (
  select
    CP_REF, ADI,
    case
        when ADI <  1.32 and COV * COV <  0.49 then 'Smooth'
        when ADI >= 1.32 and COV * COV <  0.49 then 'Intermittent'
        when ADI <  1.32 and COV * COV >= 0.49 then 'Erratic'
        when ADI >= 1.32 and COV * COV <= 0.49 then 'Lumpy'
        else 'Smooth'
    end as StatusOrWhatever
  from data
)
select stuff
from DF_ALL_DEMAND_BY_ROW_V v
left join Q2 on D2.CF_REF = v.CP_REF
```

Comment: It's not working. It says `No column specified for column 4 in Q2`.

Comment: Ah yes I'd just used your query - you need to give the case expression an alias.